# addEventListener 'submit' working properly when clicking on button but not when pressing enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, form-submit

it's my first time using the submit event on a form. Rather than submitting, I have used preventDefault() and then added some code to execute a search. When I press the search button, it works properly, creating a div where it loads the search results. When I press enter, it works properly up to the point where it has to append the new div to the html.

This is the function that creates the div

```
const crearDivResultados = function() {
    const divResultados = document.createElement('div');
    divResultados.setAttribute("id", "resultados");
    contenedorResultados.append(divResultados);
}
```

This is the rest of the code.

```
const formulario = document.forms.buscador
formulario.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let inputValor = inputBusqueda.value;
    contenedorResultados.innerHTML = '';
    crearTitulo(inputValor, contenedorResultados);
    crearDivResultados();
    let resultados = document.querySelector('#resultados');
    console.log(resultados);
    buscarGifs(inputValor).then (resp => {
        mostrarResultados(resp.data);
    })

    botonBusquedaDesplegado.style.display = 'none';
    contenedorResultados.style.display = 'block';
    resultados.style.display = 'flex';
})
```

The error (Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: resultados is not defined) appears in this line of code:

`let resultados = document.querySelector('#resultados');`

ONLY when submitting with enter key. When clicking the button it works just fine.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Possibly related: is your form a single input and submit button? or are there multiple form elements (input/select/etc) inside the form?

Answer (score 0):

Event type **Submit** means the submit button is clicked. If you want to listen to another event type, use **keypress**